# How to make a Like plugin for applicaiton

Tags: facebook

How can I make a like plugin for a particular application image? There is an application and in that application there are a lot of images. Now I want to make a Like plugin for that image?

For example see this...

[http://www.facebook.com/plugin​s/like.php?app_id=252721458092​173&href=http%3A%2F%2Fopenapps​.zapak.com%2Fpepsiphotocontest​%2Fpepsi.php%3Flikedid%3D10000​0548118486_Independence-2.jpg&​send=false&layout=standard&wid​th=80&show_faces=true&action=l​ike&colorscheme=light&font&hei​ght=80](http://www.facebook.com/plugin%E2%80%8Bs/like.php?app_id=252721458092%E2%80%8B173&href=http://openapps%E2%80%8B.zapak.com/pepsiphotocontest%E2%80%8B/pepsi.php?likedid=10000%E2%80%8B0548118486_Independence-2.jpg&%E2%80%8Bsend=false&layout=standard&wid%E2%80%8Bth=80&show_faces=true&action=l%E2%80%8Bike&colorscheme=light&font&hei%E2%80%8Bght=80)

I want to make a Like plugin like the above for my image in the application. Here is the link which I want to convert into a Like plugin..

apps. facebook. com /ntwovcontest / contests /7 / images / 3866

[http://contest.n2v.com/contest​s/7/images/3866](http://contest.n2v.com/contest%E2%80%8Bs/7/images/3866)

App id = 137809049643292

Answer (score 0):

You should create Open Graph Protocol tags for each image (which requires you to create a unique URL for each image), and then link each like button the related OG endpoint.

The docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ should get you started.